# $_POST de variáveis dinâmicas

Tags: php, jquery

Olá, 
Estou com problemas para resgatar por `$_POST` depois de submeter o formulário valores de campos dinâmicos adicionados com `jQuery`.

Estou conseguindo popular os selects da mesma linha e tudo está funcionando, o grande problema é: Quando tento pegar todas as informações por `POST` após submeter o formulário, só são exibidas as informações da primeira linha.

**Código HTML**

```
      <form action = "abrir-inscricoes.php" method = "post">
                    <tr><th>Nível</th>
                        <th>Programa</th>
                        <th>Semestre</th>
                        <th>Ano</th>
                        <th>Data Inicial</th>
                        <th>Data Final</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody style="background-color: #7AA3CC;">                        
                        <tr style="background-color: #7AA3CC;" class="linha">
                            <td>
                                <select class="select_nivel" name="niveis[]">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none">Nivel</option>
                                    <?php
                                        $qtdreg = sizeof($niveis);
                                        for ($i=0; $i<$qtdreg; $i++) {
                                            echo "<option value=\"".$niveis[$i]['id']."\">".$niveis[$i]['descricao']."</option>";
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </td>

                            <td><select class="select_programa" name="programas[]">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none">Programa</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <select class="select_semestre" name="semestres[]">
                                    <option value="" style="display:none" disabled selected>Semestre</option>
                                    <option value="1">Primeiro</option>
                                    <option value="2">Segundo</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select class="select_ano" name="anos[]">
                                    <option value="" style="display:none" disabled selected>Ano</option>
                                    <option value="<?= $ano ?>" ><?= $ano ?></option>
                                    <option value="<?= $ano + 1 ?>" ><?= $ano + 1 ?></option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="dt_inicial" name="dt_iniciais[]" style="width: 92px;" value=""></td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="dt_final" name="dt_finais[]" style="width: 92px" value=""></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="adicionar"><td><a style="cursor:pointer" id="adicionar">+ Alterar outra inscrição</a></td>
                            <td><a style="cursor:pointer" id="alterar_tudo">+ Alterar todas as inscrições</a></td></tr>

                        <tr style="background-color: #7AA3CC;">
                            <td><input type="submit" class="botao-abrir-inscricao" value="Enviar"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color: #99ddff;">                   
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </form>
```

Código `jQuery` para adicionar campos:

```
$('#informacoes').on('click',"#adicionar",  function(){    
            var linha = $('.linha').eq(0).clone();  
            linha.find('select').val('');

            $('.adicionar').before(linha);
});
```

Tentando exibir os valores do $_POST:

```
if (isset($_POST["programas"]))      
            var_dump($_POST);
```

Agradeço desde já!

HTML GERADO APÓS ADICIONAR 1 OPÇÃO

```
<tbody style="background-color: #7AA3CC;">                        
                        <tr style="background-color: #7AA3CC;" class="linha">
                            <td>
                                <select class="select_nivel" name="niveis[]">
                                    <option value="" disabled="" selected="" style="display:none">Nivel</option>
                                    <option value="1">Mestrado</option><option value="2">Doutorado</option><option value="3">Especial</option>                                    </select>
                            </td>

                            <td><select class="select_programa" name="programas[]">
                                    <option value="" disabled="" selected="" style="display:none">Programa</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <select class="select_semestre" name="semestres[]">
                                    <option value="" style="display:none" disabled="" selected="">Semestre</option>
                                    <option value="1">Primeiro</option>
                                    <option value="2">Segundo</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select class="select_ano" name="anos[]">
                                    <option value="" style="display:none" disabled="" selected="">Ano</option>
                                    <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                    <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="dt_inicial" name="dt_iniciais[]" style="width: 92px;" value=""></td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="dt_final" name="dt_finais[]" style="width: 92px" value=""></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="background-color: #7AA3CC;" class="linha">
                            <td>
                                <select class="select_nivel" name="niveis[]">
                                    <option value="" disabled="" selected="" style="display:none">Nivel</option>
                                    <option value="1">Mestrado</option><option value="2">Doutorado</option><option value="3">Especial</option>                                    </select>
                            </td>

                            <td><select class="select_programa" name="programas[]">
                                    <option value="" disabled="" selected="" style="display:none">Programa</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <select class="select_semestre" name="semestres[]">
                                    <option value="" style="display:none" disabled="" selected="">Semestre</option>
                                    <option value="1">Primeiro</option>
                                    <option value="2">Segundo</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select class="select_ano" name="anos[]">
                                    <option value="" style="display:none" disabled="" selected="">Ano</option>
                                    <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                    <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="dt_inicial" name="dt_iniciais[]" style="width: 92px;" value=""></td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="dt_final" name="dt_finais[]" style="width: 92px" value=""></td>
                        </tr><tr style="background-color: #7AA3CC;" class="linha">
                            <td>
                                <select class="select_nivel" name="niveis[]">
                                    <option value="" disabled="" selected="" style="display:none">Nivel</option>
                                    <option value="1">Mestrado</option><option value="2">Doutorado</option><option value="3">Especial</option>                                    </select>
                            </td>

                            <td><select class="select_programa" name="programas[]">
                                    <option value="" disabled="" selected="" style="display:none">Programa</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <select class="select_semestre" name="semestres[]">
                                    <option value="" style="display:none" disabled="" selected="">Semestre</option>
                                    <option value="1">Primeiro</option>
                                    <option value="2">Segundo</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select class="select_ano" name="anos[]">
                                    <option value="" style="display:none" disabled="" selected="">Ano</option>
                                    <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                    <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="dt_inicial" name="dt_iniciais[]" style="width: 92px;" value=""></td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="dt_final" name="dt_finais[]" style="width: 92px" value=""></td>
                        </tr><tr class="adicionar"><td><a style="cursor:pointer" id="adicionar">+ Alterar outra inscrição</a></td>
                            <td><a style="cursor:pointer" id="alterar_tudo">+ Alterar todas as inscrições</a></td></tr>

                        <tr style="background-color: #7AA3CC;">
                            <td><input type="submit" class="botao-abrir-inscricao" value="Enviar"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color: #99ddff;">                   
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: Só vem o último valor? esse é o problema?

Comment: Só pega o valor da primeira linha, que não foi adicionada dinamicamente (apenas populada dinamicamente).

Comment: Para mandar um campo vários valore vc adiciona colchetes no name. faça um teste e poste o html gerado por esse javascript.

Comment: Eu usei o colchetes, está no código

Comment: inclui o html gerado que pediu

Comment: Usou a tag Ajax, mas não vi nenhum ajax no teu código, use tags apenas relevantes ao problema, entenda como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: Parece tudo em dia .... em algum momento vc remove o `disabled` dos campos do form?

Comment: Tem ajax sim, estou populando os selects via ajax, mas não coloquei aqui pois isso está funcionando!

Comment: Removo sim! Tanto que consigo popular os selects dinamicamente, o único problema está sendo para resgatar por post!